# Rails: Post parameter is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, parameters

From a javascript file I am having post request with parameters:

```
  Parameters: {"interview"=>{"participants"=>"1,2,3", "start_time"=>"2020-05-28T09:32:00.000Z", "end_time"=>"2020-05-28T10:32:00.000Z"}}
```

And i am accessing this in controller's create as:

```
puts("create entry")
@start_time =  params[:start_time]
@end_time =  params[:end_time]
p(@start_time)
p(@end_time)
participants = params[:participants].try(:split, ",")
p(participants)
```

But when check the values of p and puts are such as:

```
create entry
nil
nil
nil
```

I could not understand what is the reason behind this.

Comment: They're all "under" the `interview` key, so it should be `params[:interview][:start_time]`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Oh got my mistake. That was a silly mistake. thanks

Answer (score 1):

They're all "under" the interview key, so it should be:

```
@start_time = params[:interview][:start_time]
@end_time = params[:interview][:end_time]
participants = params[:interview][:participants].try(:split, ',')
```

Better in this case using `dig`:

```
participants = params.dig(:interview, :participants).try(:split, ',')
...
```

Or storing `params[:interview]` and giving a "default" value if `nil`:

```
interview = params[:interview] || {}
```